# jquery caption plugin for different images heights and new loaded images

Tags: php, jquery, image, jquery-plugins, caption

I tried using Mosaic (http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/) as a jQuery caption plugin (I need the 'slide up' effect) but this one didn't work for images with different height, and I had to change my html structure.

I also tried Capty (http://iwantaneff.in/repo/plugins/effects-ui/capty/index.html) but this one does not work on images that I load with infinitescroll when I reach the bottom of my page. Because it uses the .hover() function instead of the .on() function.

Where can I find a jQuery caption plugin that supports this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a html5, css3, transition combination
http://jsfiddle.net/hashie5/5p7Jk/